# Trace of a crossproduct-matrix - a faster computation?

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra, parallel-processing, multicore

I am looking for a fast computation in R of the trace (trace(A)) of a matrix A = B' C. The fastest way I can think of is the following:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 10^6
B <- matrix(rnorm(n), ncol=sqrt(n))
C <- matrix(rnorm(n), ncol=sqrt(n))

ptm <- proc.time()
A <- tcrossprod(B,C)
traceA <- sum(diag(A))
proc.time() - ptm
```

I am asking myself if there is a faster way (especially if matrix B and matrix C are symmetric or even idempotent). I mean with the line `A <- tcrossprod(B,C)` I am computing the whole matrix A, although I just need the sum of the diagonal elements of the matrix (trace(A)).

To speed this up, I thought of a parallel computation for `tcrossprod`, but I havn't found an implementation for this (additionally I don't know if this would be a good idea). Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Tr(B'C) is just the inner product of the matrices B and C viewed as vectors.  Thus

```
sum(B*C)
```

does the trick and is several orders of magnitude faster in this example.

Comment: Okay thanks! I forgot to mention that in reality I have a recursive computation for the matrix A. For example: `A(k) = A(k-1) + crossprod(B,A(k-1))`. And I need the trace of `A(k)` for step `k`. So if I use your suggestion: `trace(A(k)) = sum(diag(A(k-1)) + sum(A(k-1)*B)` but without knowing the full matrix `A(k-1)`, the trace for `A(k)` cannot be computed, right? I think I have to edit my description.

Comment: Just to complement this great answer, in the more general case where B is size $N\times K$ and C $K \times N$, you would need to use `sum(t(B) * C)`.